# How can I use an autoincrement variable in sqlite?

Tags: java, sqlite

this is my code in sqlite:
stmt.execute("create table if not exists people (name text,ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)");

but when I see my table in Navicat and when I want to use it all of it is null. I want to use it like an integer (1,2,...). What should I do? 
please help me...

Comment: Maybe instead of "not exists" try drop table before create. It sounds like you already have an invalid table because it is impossible to have a table with a null-value primary key

Comment: thanks...I tried deleting db file and create it one more time and it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google query turned out with this result:

**Summary**

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.
>
> In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the
>   ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed
>   integer.
>
> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
>   explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
>   unused integer, usually the one more than the largest ROWID currently
>   in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.
>
> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that
>   changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse
>   of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the
>   purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
>   previously deleted rows.

Reference: 
[AutoIncrement SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)